# Which of IQueryable or IEnumerable should I use to don't put rows in memory?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I want to get data from context in a `class` out of my *aspx* code behind,as this:

```
MyClass.GetIt().Skip((page - 1) * perPage).Take(perPage);
```

but I don't know which of these methods should I use that in my paging not all rows put in memory?

1.

```
public static IQueryable<T> GetIt()
{
     return context.MyObject.Where(i=>i.Type==1);
}
```

2.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetIt()
{
     return context.MyObject.Where(i=>i.Type==1);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one - `IQueryable<T>`.

Returning `IEnumerable` would cause taking all matching elements from DB into memory and would perform `Skip` and `Take` as LINQ to object query.